# PhantomJS 2.0 text not selectable when rendered to PDF

Tags: qt, pdf, fonts, phantomjs, renderer

Before few days I compiled PhantomJS 2.0 from [source](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) on `Linux Debian`. It compiled successfully, unfortunately there is a problem with web-fonts - when rendered to PDF, you can NOT select the text in the PDF, it's like a image. I'm using the following CSS code to set the fonts:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url("/public/styles/fonts/lato-300.ttf"); }

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url("/public/styles/fonts/lato-400.ttf"); }
```

The font are getting rendered, but the text is not select-able. However if I don't set any font-family and just leave the default browser font the text is select-able and everything is fine.

I have tried using `SVG, WOFF and TTF` formats - the result is the same. This issue doesn't exists in 1.9, but I can't use 1.9 because of missing features.
I can NOT also copy the font files from 1.9 branch to 2.0, because they're using different version of QT/webkit.

Comment: you ever get an update on this - running to exact same problem!

Comment: Same here but only on Linux, Windows is fine

Answer (score 1):

For webfonts (like **google fonts**) to work properly on the **`render`** one needs to install them on the running system. Otherwise QT will render the page as bitmap because the fonts are not available.

I ended switching the page to fonts that are available to the system locally, which produces much better (native) results.